# Oclgrind - Can't get it to work

Tags: opencl

I've downloaded the windows binary from https://github.com/jrprice/Oclgrind/releases but I get segfaults all over the place.

Would be nice if someone with experience with this tool can tell me if following is supposed to work:

- Use the `-I ./` build option so kernels can use include files relative to the working directory
- Are structs supported yet? I've seen there is a test for it but I get a segfault as soon as I try something like [this](https://github.com/jrprice/Oclgrind/blob/master/tests/kernels/alignment/packed.cl). If someone has the tool installed it would be interesting if that test-case works.

Any help appreciated - Got a weird memory bug and I really need something like Oclgrind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oclgrind does support both the `-I` build option and structs. There was an issue with `struct` types on Windows with previous versions of Oclgrind, due to a bug in the Clang frontend. The [latest release](https://github.com/jrprice/Oclgrind/releases) of Oclgrind uses Clang+LLVM 3.6, which should fix these issues.

<s>However, there is indeed an issue with structs on Windows at the moment. Attempting to compile any kernel that uses a struct results in a segmentation fault. This is actually a bug in the version of Clang that Oclgrind is using, not in Oclgrind itself. Structs work fine when using Oclgrind on Linux or OS X.</s>

<s>This is an unfortunate issue, as many codes make use of structs. At some point Oclgrind will be updated to use a newer version of Clang/LLVM, which should hopefully resolve this issue. There is an [LLVM 3.6 branch in the GitHub repository](https://github.com/jrprice/Oclgrind/tree/llvm_36) that compiles against Clang+LLVM 3.6, which fixes this bug.</s>

Comment: thanks for your answer - so it might work if i use the latest llvm + clang release and build oclgrind with it?

Comment: @Daniel It might do, but it almost certainly won't build with the latest LLVM + Clang out-of-the-box. It currently uses LLVM 3.2 and a patched version of Clang that supports SPIR 1.2 generation.

Comment: i guess i will try to build it with the latest llvm release and also try to use a linux vm to run oclgrind. will answer back if something works

Comment: @Daniel The Linux VM should definitely work. If you encounter any other problems, do let me know.